# Bash Script cd not working even it exists

Tags: bash, unix

I am running a bash script in unix. The directory exists but it wont work when i change directory in the script.

The script is located at: /oracle/archive.sh

I run the script with: sh archive.sh

Script:

```
SALES_DIR="/oracle/sales/"
cd $SALES_DIR
pwd
```

The output show:

: No such file or directory: /oracle/sales/

/oracle

It clearly show that it is not able to change the directory, but the pwd command is working.

Comment: Your error message is not consistent with the script. The script has a leading slash: `SALES_DIR="/oracle/sales/"`, but the error message doesn't: `No such file or directory: oracle/sales/`. If the leading slash is missing in the script, then the `cd` is equivalent to `cd /oracle/oracle/sales`. If the leading slash is present in the script (and you didn't type the error message correctly) then there is no such directory `/oracle/sales`.

Comment: @DavidHammen sorry i forgot to add the slash in the error message, it does exists..i re-edited the post

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the directory with the name sales exists under oracle and that the file named sales is really a directory?

Comment: @TimRijavec ya i am able to change directory in terminal using: cd /oracle/sales/

Comment: What editor did you use to write the script? Try and run `tr -d "\r" < archive.sh > archive.new.sh` in the /oracle directory and then run `sh archive.new.sh`.

Comment: @TimRijavec notetpad++, then ftp to server with ascii mode, tried your command, it works. Why?

Comment: Did you run the command on the server? Please run `cat -ve archive.sh` and `cat -ve archive.new.sh` and paste the output. That should show special characters in your script if there are any.

Comment: @TimRijavec Sorry your command is working. Why is that?

Comment: I'm glad that worked. Please see my answer below and accept it (mark answer as accepted) if you find it useful.

Comment: @TimRijavec sure, accepted and up voted... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was that you were using editor which saved your script with CR character (more about that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline. With tr, you've converted the script to use only Unix end-of-lines characters (LF), saying that you removed the \r character from the script.

```
tr -d "\r" < archive.sh > archive.new.sh
```

You can also detect special characters when running

```
cat -ve archive.sh
```

So in your case instead of changing directory to `/oracle/sales/` you were actually trying to cd to `/oracle/sales/\r`