# Not able to run a file on boot rasperry pi due to "from: not found"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, discord.py, startup

So I was trying to run my discord bot on my raspberry pi on boot but the problem is when i tried test running it using the command `$ sudo /etc/init.d/bot.py start` and i recieved the following output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/init.d $ sudo /etc/init.d/bot.py start
/etc/init.d/bot.py: 1: from: not found
/etc/init.d/bot.py: 2: import: not found
/etc/init.d/bot.py: 3: from: not found
/etc/init.d/bot.py: 4: from: not found
/etc/init.d/bot.py: 5: import: not found
: not found/bot.py: 6: 
/etc/init.d/bot.py: 8: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I have installed all the modules and the code runs fine in my IDE (The default Thonny IDE for python)

This is my first 8 lines of code:

```py
from socket import socket, timeout
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from mcstatus import MinecraftServer
import urllib.request

#------------------------------------------------------------
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '.')
```

Answer (score 2):

In order for your script to be recognized as a Python file, the first line of it should be

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

It also needs to have the executable bit set (`chmod +x bot.py`).

Comment: It gives me this error now `/usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Now you appear to have introduced a Carriage Return (`\r`) at the end of the line - are you using an editor from Windows? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35626727/2836621

Comment: yes, i had coded the file in windows. then uploaded to my raspberry pi

Comment: I copied the code and deleted the file and made a new file and pasted it. and it ran in the test run. but when i booted. the file did not run.